# Unity C# Bounce off Wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a 3D pool game. Basically I have a main camera that when you press a button it adds force to the cue ball based on the position of the camera, which works ok.

But whenever the cue ball hits the wall of the table, it just stops. I want it to smoothly bounce off the wall like a real pool cue ball would.

The cue ball is just a basic sphere Game Object. The walls are basic cubes with colliders.

I have tried `Vector3.Reflect` with no success. It seems to bounce back a tiny bit but then immediately stops.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you please provide your code using `Vector3.Reflect`?

Answer (score 5):

You should create a `PhysicMaterial` with low or no friction (both `dynamic` and `static`), `bounciness = 1` and `Bounce Combine = Maximum` and then apply that `PhysicMaterial` to the `rigidbody` of your sphere

Comment: Ok this works, it just seems like the third or fourth time it hits the wall it stops bouncing. Maybe something to do with my sphere's rotation being frozen?

Comment: Rotation freeze shouldn't affect this (though for a pool game, spin is fairly important so maybe you shouldn't freeze rotation). I'm not sure what your problem is due to, perhaps other physics constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.

Store the ball velocity when it collide with the wall, calculate the reflected direction through Vector3.Reflect and give the stored velocity to the ball in reflected direction.

Hope that this will help you...

Best,
 Hardik.

Comment: I might've misunderstood buy OP seems to say that he's tried this exactly before without success. Maybe if he provides some code we can figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

To make bounce on wall we need to create physic material and after that we need to change the value of **dynamic friction** =0.3 and **static friction** =
0.3 and **bounciness**=0.8 and **frictionCombine** choose **Average** from dropdown and **bouncecombine** choose **Average** .
Hence the ball is start bouncing on the wall by using the upper property.